# @Component Scan Not Working with @Component In Spring Boot across jar and war

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, war

I am having a common jar file in spring boot application this way,

```
package com.acc.api;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.acc.api","service"})
public class ApicoreApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(ApicoreApplication.class, args);

        for (String name: applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }

}
```

And components in this are,

```
package com.acc.api.core.utils;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AccUtil {

    @Autowired
    private WebServiceEngine engine;

}
```

where WebServiceEngine is an third party api i cam calling.

And my pom entries are like these,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.acc.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>apicore</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>apicore</name>
    <description>apicore</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.23</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>WebServiceEngine</groupId>
            <artifactId>WebServiceEngine</artifactId>
            <version>7.10.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Till this its fine, project is compiling and jar is getting created in target folder.

Now I am using this jar in the other spring boot war file this way,

```
<?xml version="1.0"
 encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.acc.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>maintenance</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.acc.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>test</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>               
    <dependency>
                <groupId>com.acc.api</groupId>
                <artifactId>apicore</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.23</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>maintenance</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy war</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.war</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And my springboot classes in war files are like these,

```
package com.acc.api;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class MaintenanceApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(MaintenanceApplication.class, args);
        }

    }

    package com.acc.api;

    import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
    import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

    public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(MaintenanceApplication.class);
        }

    }
```

And my actual controller where i am using that above jar in this `MaintenanceApplication` war file is,

```
    package com.acc.api.controller;

    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

    import com.acc.api.core.utils.AccUtil;

    @Import({AccUtil.class})
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/STATUS")
    public class StatusController {

        private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StatusController.class);

        @Autowired
        private AccUtil accUtil;

        @Autowired
        private ObjectMapper objMapper;

        @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/fetchStatus")
        public String getStatus(@PathVariable String processId){
            String status = "";
            try {           
                    status =  accUtil.getStats();
                    return status;
            }   
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

IDE is not showing any errors, But I am getting below build errors when doing `mvn clean install`.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project maintenance: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /src/main/java/com/acc/hpi/controller/MSRController.java:[13,30] package com.acc.api.core.utils does not exist
[ERROR]   symbol:   class AccUtils
```

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your `AccUtils` is in the wrong directory.

Comment: @chrylis do you want me to move it to com.acc.api itself in the jar?

Comment: Rename your folders(package)  current is com/hcc/hpi/ change it to com/acc/api

Comment: @chrylis no no its typo mistake its in com/acc/api only and alo i tried placing AccUtil and springboot file in the same location com/acc/api but still no luck

Comment: @ Jonathan Johx no no its typo mistake its in com/acc/api only and alo i tried placing AccUtil and springboot file in the same location com/acc/api but still no luck

Comment: You cannot use on Spring Boot generated jar in another as it is packaged/structured differently. You don't want your jar to be generated by Spring Boot you want a regular jar instead.

Answer (score 1):

When using Spring Boot the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` will repackage and restructure the generated jar file. This jar file isn't useable as a dependency in other applications. Instead you need to instruct the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to repackage the jar and leave the original artifact (and publish both to your maven repository).

The Spring Boot Reference Guide has a [special section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-build.html#howto-create-an-additional-executable-jar) on how to do this.

If your jar is only a dependency and not runnable/executable by itself then just remove the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and generate a regular jar.

Answer (score 0):

You have imported `com.acc.api.core.utils.AccUtil` class **twice** in `StatusController` class:

```
import com.acc.api.core.utils.AccUtil;

@Import({AccUtil.class})
```

remove one of them and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot only scans for packages/jars that are a dependency.
Either way, compile-time scope, or run-time scope(provided).
So, if you try to scan jars that are not compile time dependend(default scope), e.g. because you integrate on a interface, you are still dependend on it runtime, so the componentscan can find the implementing class to inject.
If you wire e.g. @RestControllers, the application may be in another package/jar then your controllers.
And though you dont have a compile time dependency of the application package to the controllers, you still need to have the jar runt-time loaded. Otherwise, the controller will not be scanned and found run-time.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>...</artifactId>
        <version></version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version></version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```